# How to format protein sequence

Tags: format, sequence

I download sequences and want to handle the data in python. The first question is formatting the sequences. The sequences like this in below. Each sequence begin with ">", and the protein sequence is in the separate line. Before align the sequence. I need to get all the sequence (strings) for one line. I have tried "str.startswith", but it does not work. And I google, some people say it could be done with regular expression. Anybody can help me with this sequence. Many thanks.

'>A/Nayarit/InDRE21/2017_EPI1215815
DTLCIGYHANNSTDTVDTVLEKNVTVTHSVNLLEDKHNGKLCKLRGVVPLHLGKCNIAGWILGNPECESLSTARSWSYIV
ETSNSDNGTCYPGDFINYEELREQLSSVSSFERFEIFPKTSSWPNHDSNKGVTAACPHAGAKSFYKNLIWLVKKGNSYPK
LNQTYINDKGKEVLVLWGIHHPPTTADQQSLYQNADAYVFVGTSRYSKKFKPEIATRPKVRDQEGRMNYYWTLVEPGDKI
TFEATGNLVVPRYAFTMERNAGSGIIISDTPVHDCNTTCQTPEGAINTSLPFQNVHPITIGKCPKYVKSTKLRLATGLRN
VPSIQSRGLFGAIAGFIEGGWTGMVDGWYGYHHQNEQGSGYAADLKSTQNAIDKITNKVNSVIEKMNTQFTAVGKEFNHL
EKRIENLNKKVDDGFLDIWTYNAELLVLLENERTLDYHDSNVKNLYEKVRNQLKNNAKEIGNGCFEFYHKCDNTCMESVK
NGTYDYPKYSEEAKLNREKIDGVKLESTRIYQILAIYSTVASSLVLVVSLGAISFWMCSNGSLQCRICI
'>A/Ontario/RV2895/2018_EPI1215825
DTLCIGYHANNSTDTVDTVLEKNVTVTHSVNLLEDKHNGKLCKLRGVAPLHLGKCNIAGWILGNPECESLSTARSWSYIV
ETSNSDNGTCYPGDFINYEELREQLSSVSSFERFEIFPKTSSWPNHDSNKGVTAACSHAGAKSFYKNLIWLVKKGNSYPK
LNQTYINDKGKEVLVLWGIHHPPTTADQQSLYQNADAYVFVGTSRYSKKFKPEIATRPKVRDQEGRMNYYWTLVEPGDKI
TFEATGNLVVPRYAFTMERNAGSGIIISDTPVHDCNTTCQTPEGAINTSLPFQNVHPITIGKCPKYVKSTKLRLATGLRN
VPSIQSRGLFGAIAGFIEGGWTGMVDGWYGYHHQNEQGSGYAADLKSTQNAIDKITNKVNSVIEKMNTQFTAVGKEFNHL
EKRIENLNKKVDDGFLDIWTYNAELLVLLENERTLDYHDSNVKNLYEKVRTQLKNNAKEIGNGCFEFYHKCDNTCMESVK
NGTYDYPKYSEEAKLNREKIDGVKLESTRIYQILAIYSTVASSLVLVVSLGAISFWMCSNGSLQCRICI
'>A/Ontario/RV2906/2018_EPI1215828
DTLCIGYHANNSTDTVDTVLEKNVTVTHSVNLLEDKHNGKLCKLGGVAPLHLGKCNIAGWILGNPECESLSTARSWSYIV
ETSNSDNGTCYPGDFINYEELREQLSSVSSFERFEIFPKTSSWPNHDSNKGVTAACPHAGAKSFYKNLIWLVKKGNSYPK
LNQTYINDKGKEVLVLWGIHHPPTTADQQSLYQNADAYVFVGTSRYSKKFKPEIATRPKVRDQEGRMNYYWTLVEPGDKI
TFEATGNLVAPRYAFTMERNAGSGIIISDTPVHDCNTTCQTAEGAINTSLPFQNVHPVTIGKCPKYVKSTKLRLVTGLRN
VPSIQSRGLFGAIAGFIEGGWTGMVDGWYGYHHQNEQGSGYAADLKSTQNAIDKITNKVNSVIEKMNTQFTAVGKEFNHL
EKRIENLNKKVDDGFLDIWTYNAELLVLLENERTLDYHDSNVKNLYEKVRNQLKNNAKEIGNGCFEFYHKCDNTCMESVK
NGTYDYPKYSEEAKLNREKIDGVKLESTRIYQILAIYSTAASSLVLVVSLGAISFWMCSNGSLQCRICI
'>A/Nova Scotia/RV2907/2018_EPI1215830
DTLCIGYHANNSTDTVDTVLEKNVTVTHSVNLLEDKHNGKLCKLGGVAPLHLGKCNIAGWILGNPECESLSTARSWSYIV
ETSNSDNGTCYPGDFINYEELREQLSSVSSFERFEIFPKTSSWPNHDSNKGVTAACPHAGAKSFYKNLIWLVKKGNSYPK
LNQTYINDKGKEVLVLWGIHHPPTTADQQSLYQNADAYVFVGTSRYSKKFKPEIATRPKVRDQEGRMNYYWTLVGPGDKI
TFEATGNLVVPRYAFTMERNAGSGIIISDTPVHDCNTTCQTAEGAINTSLPFQNVHPVTIGKCPKYVKSTKLRLATGLRN
VPSIQSRGLFGAIAGFIEGGWTGMVDGWYGYHHQNEQGSGYAADLKSTQNAIDKITNKVNSVIEKMNTQFTAVGKEFNHL
EKRIENLNKKVDDGFLDIWTYNAELLVLLENERTLDYHDSNVKNLYEKVRNQLKNNAKEIGNGCFEFYHKCDNTCMESVK
NGTYDYPKYSEEAKLNREKIDGVKLESTRIYQILAIYSTVASSLVLVVSLGAISFWMCSNGSLQCRICI